# Swift - JSQMessagesViewController for ios 7?

Tags: swift, ios7, chat, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I want to build a chat application using JSQMessagesViewController.

Is there a way to run JSQMessagesViewController on iOS7 or later, or if not, are there any alternatives or a similar library available?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You may want to add this at `JSQMessagesCollectionViewCell`:

`(void)setBounds:(CGRect)bounds { [super setBounds:bounds]; self.contentView.frame = bounds; }`

Besides, the [documentation](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/JSQMessagesViewController/7.3.3/) clearly shows support for iOS 7+

Edit: you just need to change one build setting in your casual Xcode iOS Universal Framework target (set Mach-O Type to Static Library):

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qIC1X.png)

Comment: Error when I built on iOS 7
https://scontent-hkg3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t34.0-12/13695773_506392769570477_1768908965_n.png?oh=0e5b45b927983aa2c4a5a90def3b6005&oe=578B7975

Comment: Please mark the answer correct if it solves your problem